# Publicly exposing a WCF restful service via http from Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to expose a WCF based restful service via http and am so far unsuccessful. I'm trying on my local machine first so prove it works. I found a suggestion [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf/) that I remove my local cluster and then manually run this powershell command from the SF SDK folder as administrator to recreate it with the machine name binding: .\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -UseMachineName

It created the cluster successfully. I can use the SF Explorer and see in the cluster manifest that entries in the NodeList show the machine name rather than localhost. This seems good.

But the first problem I notice is that if I expand my way through SF Explorer down to the node my app is running on I see an endpoints entry but the URL is not what I'd expect. I am seeing this: http://surfacelap/d5be9425-3247-4290-b77f-1a90f728fb8d/39cda0f7-cef4-4c7f-8af2-d05786a834b0-131111019607641260

Is that what I should see even though I have an endpoint setup? I did not expect the guid and other numbers in the path. This makes me suspect that SF is not seeing my service as being publicly accessible and instead is maybe only setup for internal access within the app? If I dig down into my service manifest I see this as expected:

```
<Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Name="ResolverEndpoint" Protocol="http" Type="Input" Port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

But how do I know if the service itself is mapped to it? When I use the crazy long url above and try a simple method of my service I get an http 202 response and no response data as expected. If I then change the method name to one that doesn't exist I get the same thing, not the expected http 404. I've tried using both my machine name and localhost. Same result.

So clearly I'm doing something wrong. Below is my CreateServiceInstanceListeners override. In it you can see I use "ResolverEndpoint" as my endpoint resource name, which matches the service manifest:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
            new WcfCommunicationListener<IResolverV2>(
                serviceContext: context,
                wcfServiceObject: new ResolverServiceV2(),
                listenerBinding: new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None),
                endpointResourceName: "ResolverEndpoint"
            )
        )};
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get it to work: https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc

Essential changes to your code are the use of the public name of your cluster as endpoint URL and an additional `WebHttpBehavior` behavior on that endpoint.

Comment: Yep, this looks very much like what I've put together with the help of Vipul. The only difference I see in yours is the HostFromConfig() logic. Why is it that you think this is necessary rather than always relying on context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN? I've deployed to an Azure cluster without that logic, are there scenarios where you saw that as necessary?

Comment: No, you're right. Changing the ServiceInstanceListener so it doesn't use endpointResourceName but address is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint resources specified in the service manifest is shared by all of the replica listeners in the process that use the same endpoint resource name. So if your service has more than one partition it is possible that more than one replica from different partition may end up in the same process. In order to differentiate the messages addressed to different partitions, the listener adds partition ID and additional instance GUID to the path.

If you are going to have a singleton partition service and know that there will not be more than one replicas in the same process you can directly supply EndpointAddress you want to the listener to open at. Use the CodePackageActivationContext API to get the port from the endpoint resource name, node name or IP address from the NodeContext and then provide the path you want the listener to open at.

Here is the code in the WcfCommunicationListener that constructs the Listen Address.

```
  private static Uri GetListenAddress(
        ServiceContext serviceContext,
        string scheme,
        int port)
    {
        return new Uri(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0}://{1}:{2}/{5}/{3}-{4}",
                scheme,
                serviceContext.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN,
                port,
                serviceContext.PartitionId,
                serviceContext.ReplicaOrInstanceId,
                Guid.NewGuid()));
    }
```

Please note that you can now have only once application, one service and one partition on a node and when you are testing locally, keep the instance count of that service as 1. When deployed in the actual cluster you can use -1 instance count.

Comment: So you are showing me how the WcfCommunicationListener works currently. That is interesting, but I am really looking for guidance on how I can make it work for me and this not obvious. How do I make it not append the Partition/Replica info to the address? Do I need to override the Wcf listener and change the OpenAsymc method?

Comment: VipuIM, A super simple ICalculator type sample app that exposes a public WCF based WebApi would make this so much easier to understand. Can you help me put on together that we can put into github for others to use?

Comment: Feel free to start a sample and send me to link to the code. Use the constructor of the listener that directly takes the endpoint address instead of passing the endpoint resource name.